# Python Code error "Process finished with exit code 0"

Tags: python-3.x

My code is to input 10 integers from user and return the max odd number entered but its not working.

Code :

```
def myolution (self, numbers):
    numbers = [input('Enter values') for i in range(10)]
    odds = [y for y in numbers if y % 2 != 0]
    if odds:
        return max(odds)
    else:
        return 'All even'
```

I get this message : Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Your code does not call your function. All it does is declaring a function and doing nothing with it. `Process finished with exit code 0` is a message from your shell, that Python interpreter completed without errors.

Comment: Even if it did call the function, that wouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 problems with your code

1. you don't use `self` and `numbers` from your function signature at all.
2. `input` return a string, so you need to transform it to a number.
3. you don't execute your function, that only defined it, you need to explicitly call it.

here is the fixed version

```
def myolution():
    numbers = [int(input('Enter a value: ')) for i in range(10)]
    odds = [y for y in numbers if y % 2 != 0]
    if odds:
        return max(odds)
    else:
        return 'All even'

print(myolution())
```